# Create a calculated field in a MongoDB aggregation

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Experts,

I'm new to this and trying to create a calculated field in a MongoDB aggregation. I have collections called Player, Response, and Clue. The response table has 3 fields (other than its own _id):

PID: the _id of the player giving the response

QID: the _id of the clue being responded to

Place: 0 if the response was incorrect, otherwise a positive integer (corresponding to the order of responses, so the first correct response gets place 1)

How can I count the number of correct responses given by a player? This is obvious with a SQL query (sum(case when place > 0 then 1 else 0 end)), but I'm having trouble wrapping my head around it in MongoDB. Here's what I have right now. As it is, this code works and gives the correct number of attempts for each player, but when I un-comment the commented-out $project step (and the correctAnswers: {$sum: '$Correct'}), ans becomes an empty array:

```
const ans = await Player.aggregate([
{
  $match: { PK: { $in: [2, 10] } },
},
{
  $lookup: {
    from: Response.collection.name,
    localField: '_id',
    foreignField: 'PID',
    as: 'Response',
  },
},
{ $unwind: '$Response' },
{
  $project: {
    eMail: 0,
    password: 0,
    passwordChangedAt: 0,
  },
},
// {
//   $project: {
//     Correct: {
//       $cond: {
//         if: { $gt: ['$Response.place', 0] },
//         then: 1,
//         else: 0,
//       },
//     },
//   },
// },
{
  $lookup: {
    from: Clue.collection.name,
    localField: 'Response.QID',
    foreignField: '_id',
    as: 'Clue',
  },
},
{
  $match: {
    'Clue.month': 11,
    'Clue.year': 2020,
  },
},
{ $unwind: '$Clue' },
{
  $group: {
    _id: {
      fName: '$fName',
      lName: '$lName',
    },
    attempts: { $sum: 1 },
    // correctAnswers: { $sum: '$Correct' },
  },
},
```

]);

Comment: can you post some sample data and expected output?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/64886691/7975771 help you to do conditional sum?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64886691/7975771 helped, and that worked. Thanks, varman.